# Применение saga redux для манипуляций с DOM

Tags: reactjs, redux

Нужно поддерживать возможность автоматического скроллинга страницы до нужного места (якоря). Приложение написано на REACT+REDUX. Будет ли правильно повесить на некоторое действие обработчик saga, который будет скролить документ до некоторого места или все же это в функции компонентов должно реализовано быть?

Comment: Это логика в 4 строчки, лучше писать в стейте компонента функцию обработчик

Answer (score 0):

Для скроллинга в проектах на `react` мне очень нравится [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll), он позволяет скроллить до заданного элемента или определенного положения относительно границ экрана и имеет кучу полезных настроек + он следит за изменениями `virtualDOM` и прекрасно работает с динамически-генерируемым контентом.

`Redux-saga` я бы использовал там, где раньше бы вы использовали `midelware` и частично редьюсеры. Т.е. для последовательного вызова экшнов в зависимости от результатов других экшнов ( без `saga` это бы делали в `midelware` ) и для реализации бизнес логики вашего приложения ( без `saga` большая часть бизнес логики содержалась бы в редьюсерах ).